# <Link> from next-intl/server causing a reload

Tags: reactjs, next.js, internationalization, i18next

I'm using nextjs v13.4 (App router) with internationalization, specifically `next-intl@3.0.0-beta.9` and following the same guide as their official docs suggest for next server-side components.
resource: [official docs for next-intl](https://next-intl-docs.vercel.app/docs/getting-started/app-router-server-components)

but I'm not getting why the Link from next-intl/server is causing the page to do a reload.

```
import {useTranslations} from 'next-intl';
import Link from 'next-intl/server';

export default function Home() {

  const t = useTranslations('Main');
  return (
   <div className='bg-rose-500'>
    <p>{t('title')}</p>

    <Link href="/en" >EN</Link>{" "}
    <Link href="/de" >DE</Link>

   </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. Any Next-Intl developer that may help us out here?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using `next/link` like this:

```
import Link from 'next/link';

<Link href="/en/about">
</Link>
```

instead of

```
import Link from 'next-intl/link';

<Link href="/about" locale="en">
</Link>
```